# How to create a multi-lingual site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, satellite-assembly

I am about to start on a project which must support a number of European languages.  All static content on this site must be translatable between these languages.  I have heard of satellite assemblies and have heard that they are used for multi-language sites in .NET but this was a long time ago.  Is this still current practice in .NET?  I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, one option would be to use a different resource for each view. I wrote an article about it, maybe it can be of help:

[ASP.NET MVC Localization: Generate resource files and localized views using custom templates](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/asp-net-mvc-localization-generate-resource-files-and-localized-views-using-custom-templates/)

Comment: We have taken this approach in one project I worked on where we had a site for global customers. Another approach is storing the static texts in a database.

Comment: @raymond: IMO it's a little bit overkill to store _static_ text in a database. I'd rather keep it simple and leave it in a resource file. Unless you have a really good reason to do it, of course :)

Comment: Yes I know, which is why I prefer resource files. Oh, I remember now why we used a database. It was to centralize static text across several applications  including an ASP.NET website, classic ASP and several desktop applications.

Answer (score 4):

Without the satellite part, you can add a `App_GlobalResources` folder to the project and add `*.resx` files for each language. You can have one resource file for the whole project, or one per ASP.NET MVC Area or however you see fit, but you don't need to have more then 1.

App_GlobalResources

```
MyResources.resx        (Neutral / Default language translated texts)
MyResources.en-GB.resx
MyResources.de-DE.resx
```

In MyResources.resx

```
Name    Value
TextID  Some text which will be localized to the end user.
```

In Global.asax.cs (`Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute`)

```
// Set it according to cookies/Session etc.
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "de-DE"; 
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "de-DE";
```

Then in the Views and PartialViews (e.g. MyView.cshtml).

```
<span>@Resources.MyResources.TextID</span>
```

**Optional:**

The Resources can be added as a link, and use custom namespaces.

```
BuildAction:           Embedded Resource
CopyToOutputDirectory: Copy always
CustomTool:            PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
CustomToolNamespace:   MyNamespaceHere
```

mToolNamespace:   MyNamespaceHere

Then they would be accessible via.

```
<span>@MyNamespaceHere.MyResources.TextID</span>
```

This is a general way to use (normal / linked) resources in ASP.NET MVC. If you use "Add as link" you can have one physical copy in a separate project.

**Satellite:**

Some info on satellite assemblies:

[MSDN: Creating Satellite Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[A MSDN Blog: Introduction to Satellite Assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies.aspx)